# When sending boolean values through Ajax call, PHP gets the value as a string

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Boolean value sent over Ajax (from client) becomes string on the server side:

```
    var ban_status = null;
    ban_status = true;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: app.baseUrl + "/admin/users/api-ban-user",
        data: { "userId": user_id, "banStatus": ban_status },
        datatype: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.status === true) {
                addAlert(response.msg, 'success');
                userList();
            } else {
                addAlert(response.msg, 'error');
            }
        }
    });
```

In php

```
$banStatus = $post['banStatus'];

gettype($post['banStatus'])
```

returns string. How to return the boolean value.

Comment: GET or POST parameters are always strings in php, you have to cast them explicetely to `number` or `bool` or `float`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned; you can use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) in php but since the post data is a string you can send one parameter called json and stringify your object in JavaScript:

```
var ban_status = null;
ban_status = true;

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: app.baseUrl + "/admin/users/api-ban-user",
  data: {json:JSON.stringify({ "userId": user_id, "banStatus": ban_status })},
  datatype: "json"
}).then(
  function (response) {
        if (response.status === true) {
            addAlert(response.msg, 'success');
            userList();
        } else {
            addAlert(response.msg, 'error');
        }
  }
).fail(//use .catch if you have a new enough jQuery
  function(err){
    console.warn("something went wrong:",err);
  }
);
```

In PHP:

```
$postedObject = json_decode($post['json']);
$banStatus = $postedObject->banStatus;
```

Answer (score 0):

use php typecating

```
$banStatus = (boolean)$post['banStatus'];
gettype($post['banStatus'])
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Use 1 instead of true, and 0 instead of false in your ajax call.
Or compare with strings in server side.
HTTP is a text protocol everything must be stringified. (int, boolean etc.)

Answer (score 0):

The point is you wanted to send a JSON, but giving the object in "data" does not do what you want. It sends data as form elements (see network inspector)

So you have to use:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ "userId": user_id, "banStatus": ban_status })
```

to send a real json-string and decode this server side via

```
json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"))
```

In addition: datatype: "json" is only the format option of the incoming response data to the javascript, not the type of data to be send to the server.

Best,
Tim